# Easing function: Ease-out-in (opposite of Ease-In-Out)

Tags: functions, bezier-curve

I'm seeking an easing function that is the twin of the popular Ease-In-Out easing function--
[image]

**Desired Behaviour**

Begins quickly, slows down in middle, ends quickly.

**References**

Keep your eye on the black portion of the screen in this *Sonic Heroes* Stage Intro animation. Notice how the black screen gives way quickly at first, slows down when the screen is half-revealed, then quickly disappears. https://youtu.be/pnLvwfvHCV4?t=71

Here's a quick reference of what the graph should look like

[image]

My attempts at curve fitting and experimentation haven't given me the equation / function I need, unfortunately. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried the inverse of the Ease-In-Out function?

Comment: The curve shown in the video appears to be simply a concatenation of two regular ease-in-out curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

$y(x) = (x^3-2x^2+x)m_0+(-2x^3+3x^2)+(x^3-x^2)m_1$

where $m_0$ and $m_1$ are two positive constants.

Bigger $m_0$ and $m_1$ will result in more wavy curve. Here are two examples:

Example 1: $m_0=m_1=3$ 
[image]

Example 2: $m_0=m_1=4$ 
[image]